# How can I create a SQL query to also include acronyms?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, synonym

Suppose I have a search for government registered charities, how can I craft my SQL query so that it also searches for acronyms of the query submitted?

For example, if I search for 'Toronto SPCA' I would like it to return the results for 'Toronto Society for the Protect and Care of Animals'

Is there a way I can write my TSQL so that it does this for me in a Freetext search?  or do I need to parse out the acronym myself before generating the TSQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could customize the thesaurus so that a fulltext search, using FORMSOF, would know that SPCA = Society for the Protection and Care of Animals.

See: [Creating Custom Thesaurus Entries in SQL Server 2005 and 2008 Full Text Search](http://arcanecode.com/2008/05/28/creating-custom-thesaurus-entries-in-sql-server-2005-and-2008-full-text-search/) for an example of how to do so.

Comment: +1: This is how I did it recently.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491%28SQL.90%29.aspx